# Getting the second element of a file

Tags: java, file

How would you get different parts of a file. This is what I mean. If I have a file that has `3215 98456 32156` how would I get the `98456`. I understand how to do `.nextInt()`, but that only gets the first element of the file. Is there a method that would grab the other parts of a file as well?

Comment: Use `nextInt()` and then `nextInt()` again? Or grab a line (`nextLine`) and `split` it by whitespace and grab index 1?

Comment: So if you use `nextInt()` twice it gets the second element. And if you use it a third time it gets the third element of a file?

Comment: Hm, the more you know! I never knew that. I was always fooling around with the `split` and it got rather confusing when I had a file with many elements, thanks! I was always under the impression that `nextInt()` just grabbed the first element of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextInt()` twice. The second calling of `nextInt()` gives you the second integer in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) an arbitrary amount of time. Call it a second time and only use the second return value. Something like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("numbers.dat"));
sc.nextInt(); //Ignore the result
int second = sc.nextInt();
//do something with second
//for example
System.out.println(second);
```